# Browse filesystem folder in VS tool window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I would like to browse a real filesystem folder in a docked window of Visual Studio (2013 Pro). The Solution Explorer only shows files I have manually added to projects. I've tried adding a folder to the project, but it only creates a virtual folder. You also cannot add file system folders via Add Existing Item. Surely I'm just missing a tool window among all the ones VS offers, since almost every other IDE and larger editor has this feature.

Where do I find the filesystem browser, or how can I hack something together to the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a solution or a project in the Solution Explorer, you can press **Show All Files** button at the top. This will show you the files and folders that were not added to a project.

Comment: Thanks! The button really doesn't show up until you select a project, and it's pretty undiscoverable IMO. While it doesn't let you browse arbitrary folders, it solves my problem nicely.